# Convergence of continuously differentiable functions on a compact interval.

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, uniform-convergence

I'm trying to figure out this excercise about convergence and could really use some help. I have partial answers that I'd like for you to check and would really appreciate hints for the others.

Let $f_k\colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ a sequence of  continuously differentiable functions on $[a,b]$, and $f_k \to f $ on $[a,b]$. Which of the following statements are true?

(a)  $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$.

(b) $(f_k)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on $[a,b]$.

(c) The sequence $(f_k')$ is point-wise convergent on $[a.b]$.

(d) If $f$ is continuously differentiable, then $(f_k')$ is point-wise convergent on $[a,b]$.

(e) If $f$ is continuously differentiable and if $(f_k'(x))$ converges for each $x$ in $[a,b]$, then $(f_k')$ is point-wise convergent to $f'$ on $[a,b]$.

Answers:

(a) Here I state that this is **false** since the sequence $f_k = x^k$ on $[0,1]$ with $k \in \mathbb{N}$ converges to
$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x<1 \\ 1,& x=1\end{cases}$

which of course is discontinuous.

(b) Using the same example as for (a) and choosing $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$,  this is **false**.

(c) Again by the same example, for $f_k'$ to converge point-wisely on $[a,b]$ it should converge to $f'$, but since $f$ is not necessarily continuous, $f'$ doesn't necessarily exist, and thus the statement must be **false**.

(d) Here is when I ran into some trouble. I have a feeling this one is true but haven't been able to prove it. Any hint here would be helpfull.

(e) Ditto.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To $d)$ consider $f_n(x)=\frac{\sin nx}{\sqrt{n}}$ on $[0,2\pi].$

Comment: @mfl So (d) would be **false** too since $f_n \to 0$ and $f_k'(x) = \sqrt{n} \cos{nx}$ and this can get arbitrarily large with n growing to infinity. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct. For example $f'_n(\pi)=(-1)^n\sqrt{n}.$

Comment: Can somebody confirm my reasoning for (c), please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For part (e) consider the following sequence on $\mathbb{R}$ or any interval containing $0$,

$$f_n(x) = \frac{x}{1+nx^2}.$$

Then

$$f'_n(x) = \frac{1-nx^2}{(1+nx^2)^2}$$

Note that $f_n(x) \rightarrow f(x) \equiv 0$ and $f'(0) = 0$.

Also, $(f'_n(x))$ converges pointwise, but $f'_n(0) \rightarrow 1 \neq f'(0).$

Hence, (e) is false.